# PHP SOAP faultcode: soap:Server

Tags: php, soap, soapfault

Googled everywhere with no luck, could anyone tell me what's going on here?

PHP version 5.2.10

trying to make a SOAP request and get this back.

```
SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] The application encountered an unhandled system exception.
```

Fault Code:
    faultcode: soap:Server

Comment: You're calling a PHP SoapServer and getting this error?  Or calling a different SoapServer from PHP and getting this error?

Comment: I'm calling a different SOAP server with PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out my problem so I will post the results as they are rare (I think).

The problem turned out to be I was connecting (And querying) to another database with the SOAP call. The User/Pass combination was not correct and was throwing an error with was causing the SOAP request to throw an error as well.

BTW not my design, just my problem

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes its because you don't have the right URL for the WSDL (endpoint) and you need to tell to set with true (that is wsdl)

In code using nusoap:

```
$client = new nusoap_client('https://something.com/etc/file.ext?WSDL', true);
```